# optimising for loops in python when iterating over two lists and matching

Tags: python

I have been using `cProfile` in Python to better understand where I should focus my efforts to reduce compute time.

Occasionaly I loop through two lists and find matching pairs based. One list contains a list of integers, the second list is a list of dicts. Usually, one list is very long and the other is very short.

Consider I have a list, `nodes`:

```
[[532134.752, 181854.93], [532132.6, 181861.504]]
```

I also have a list, `links`:

```
[{'index': 0, 'polyline': [523732, 189041, 523735, 189069]},
 {'index': 1, 'polyline': [523711, 189069, 523732, 189041]},
 {'index': 2,
  'polyline': [499766.775,
               151379.967,
               499766,
               151381,
               499763,
               151385,
               499760,
               151387,
               499756,
               151389,
               499751,
               151389,
               499750,
               151389]},
 {'index': 3,
  'polyline': [519679,
               196844,
               519683,
               196842,
               519688,
               196838,
               519699,
               196827,
               519702,
               196822,
               519705,
               196818,
               519707.203,
               196814.758,
               519708.274,
               196810.043]},
 {'index': 4,
  'polyline': [499442,
               152969,
               499445,
               152971,
               499447,
               152973,
               499448.105,
               152975.987,
               499447,
               152981]},
 {'index': 5,
  'polyline': [524647.824,
               197808.45,
               524645.358,
               197803.279,
               524643.13,
               197798.823,
               524640.346,
               197791.027,
               524639,
               197786,
               524635,
               197760,
               524634,
               197755]},
 {'index': 6,
  'polyline': [499430.818,
               152970.364,
               499432.348,
               152969.551,
               499433.862,
               152968.746,
               499437,
               152968,
               499442,
               152969]},
 {'index': 7,
  'polyline': [524647.824,
               197808.45,
               524648,
               197797,
               524643,
               197772,
               524641,
               197754]},
 {'index': 8,
  'polyline': [518334.171,
               198052.368,
               518327,
               198045,
               518325,
               198043,
               518325,
               198040,
               518325,
               198038,
               518327,
               198034,
               518337,
               198023]},
 {'index': 9,
  'polyline': [499770,
               151368,
               499770,
               151373,
               499769,
               151377,
               499766.775,
               151379.967]}]
```

I want to find those `link` records within `links` that exist in the `nodes` list.

```
localised_links = []
for node in nodes:
    for link in links:
        # the matching heuristic. Matches if the coordinates are first or last in polyline.
        if node == link['polyline'][0:2] or node == link['polyline'][-2:]:              
            localised_links.append(link)
```

How can I increase the speed of such an operation (if at all)?

Comment: I think you simply represent the graph not the optimal way: you could attach a list of links to each node such that the filtering is not necessary.

Comment: So, for each `node` record I should have a `links` key which contains a list of the `link` index's which it is a part of?

Comment: instead of using the indices, you can simply refer to the links themselves.

Comment: `[link for node,link in itertools.product(nodes,links) if node in operator.itemgetter(slice(0,2),slice(-2,None))(link['polyline'])]`

Comment: The problem seems the double for-loop, which takes O(NM) time, where N is the length of `nodes` and M is the length of `links`.  You can reduce this to O(N log(M)) by implementing binary search over `links`. To do this, sort the `links` by the first two elements, and conduct binary search instead of linear search.  Then sort the `links` by the last two elements and conduct another binary search.

Comment: Thanks @KotaMori. Could you point me to an implementation?

Comment: @Chris_Rands. Thanks but I get a `NameError: global name 'product' is not defined` error. I imported `itertools` successfully.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  The nodes in your example don't match any of the links, do they?  If so, can you provide a working example?  Also, you said one of the list is long, and the other is short.  Which is longer one?